# Comparing curves for biomarker analysis

Tags: calculus

I'm working on a project where I want to compare average biomarker concentration in a medium under two different treatments.

For the purpose of this study, if under two treatments average concentration is the sime but in treatment $A$ it is continuous and in B discontinuous, then $A$ is a better treatment than $B$. Example:

The figure below shows an example of treatment $A$ where the $x$-axis is time and the $y$-axis is biomarker concentration. (Let's assume negative values are concentration $0$.)

[image]

The figure below is an example of treatment $B$ (consider until $t=3$).

[image: Treatment B, discontinuous expression]

Average concentration is the same, as the area under the two curves is the same and the length of the experiment is the same. However, in treatment $A$ all expression occurs between $t = 0$ and $t = 1.5$ whereas in treatment $B$ it occurs in two phases.

So, to me Treatment $A$ would be preferable.

Is there a way of expressing this mathematically so that given two curves it could compare this? Essentially, I am interested in understanding whether given two curves showing biomarker expression over time expression is "continuous" or "broken through time" if that makes sense.

Comment: While characterics of curves are well studied in mathematics, you might find other insights in [SE.Digital Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your graphs and thinking at the situation I think you can assume that the functions you consider are continuous. Secondly, they're defined on a closed interval of time that you can assume being of the type $[0,a]$.

Now, if you consider two such functions $f,g:[0,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and want to compare the 'number of times they are positive' this is the same as considering the solutions of $$\max_{x\in [0,a]}\{0,f(x)\}=0$$

for $f$ and $g$ (of course you could have the case in which $f(x_0)=0$ but $f$ is positive both after and before $x_0$, but you didn't specify how to consider these cases. I will assume this doesn't count as 'being broken' since in reality a single point is hardly measurable and, provided a good sensibility of your measures, the amount of time you get a zero measure will be very short. Given this precisation, the solutions of the abive equation can be single points or intervals. You could count these, maybe numerically solving it.

PS it could happen that you have an infinite number of 'breaking intervals', but given the experimental nature of the problem, it will be very hard. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can determine how many such positive sections you have by considering how many roots the equation for the concentration has in a given interval. For this to work, you'll have to assume that the curves are continuous in the interval.

If you for instance take $B$ you would have to know that it starts out being positive. Then you find the number of roots (where the graph passes through zero) in the interval $[0,3]$, in this case two. For each root you'll have to check if the values immediately after that are positive or negative. If they are negative (and if the values on the left of the root are positive) you have a positive section, and you can skip ahead to the next root and do the same. You can of course get a computer to do this for you.

What you are essentially doing is investigating the [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

If the time segment you are interested in is $$D=[t_0;t_0+\tau],$$ for some $t_0$ such that $\tau>0$ is your duration, and you are modelling with function $$f:D\mapsto\mathbb R$$ such that $$f(t)=A\sin(\omega t+\theta),$$ where $A$ is some amplitude (of concentration or whatever), $\omega$ is the frequency (of change of the concentration or whatever) and $\theta$ is the initial phase (of concentration or whatever), then to only have one segment $$I\in[t_0;t_0+\tau]$$ such that $$\forall_{t\in I}f(t)\geq0,$$ you must always have the length of $I$ greater than or equal to $\tau/2$ (that is easy to observe: show this yourself), which, **firstly**, requires the period $T$ of $f$, which in terms of given $A$, $\omega$ and $\theta$ is provided as $$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$$ be greater or equal to said quantity, and **secondly**, both ends of $I$ must be the zeroes of $f$.

So, from the first condition we have $$\frac{\tau}2\leq\frac{2\pi}{\omega};$$
satisfying the second condition may be a bit more tricky. Notice that $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, hence we can restrict $$\theta\in[0;2\pi)$$ without loss of generality. $\theta=0$ obviously works, and any $\theta$ greater than that will work until the upper end of $I$ touches $t_0+\tau$: increasing $\theta$ further will chop $I$ off.

The first root of $f$, the lower end of $I=[t_1;t_2]$, is $$t_1=-\frac{\theta}{\omega},$$ while $$t_2=-\frac{\theta}{\omega}+\frac{\pi}{\omega},$$ which from the second condition $t_2\leq t_0+\tau$ gives $$\frac{\pi-\theta}{\omega}\leq t_0.$$

Assembling the answer, your condition is satisfied whenever the following system is satisfied:
$$\therefore\boxed{\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\tau}2\leq\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega},\\\\
\dfrac{\pi-\theta}{\omega}\leq t_0;
\end{cases}}\phantom..$$